# Can I set default number format for specyfic table column in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I just started messing around with CakePHP.

I have a table `metrics` and a column `data_multiplier`.

I have baked all code for that table.

Generated template produces something like this:

```
<td><?= $this->Number->format($metric->data_multiplier) ?></td>
```

Default number format has 3 decimal places. I need 6 decimal places, so I had to add parameter to `format` method call like this:

```
<td><?= $this->Number->format($metric->data_multiplier, ['places' => 6]) ?></td>
```

**Do I have to do it in every view that uses this table and column, or there is some way to define default format options for specyfic column in specyfic row?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did the answer help?

Comment: I was waiting for even more productive way of doing this, but looks like there is no better way in Cake. And I forgot about the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own helper.

```
<?php

App::uses('Helper', 'View', 'Number');
class AppHelper extends Helper
{        
        public function my_numberformat($val)
        {
            return $this->Number->format($val, ['places' => 6])
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
<td><?= $this->App->my_numberformat($metric->data_multiplier) ?></td>
```

And don't forget to reference the helper to your controller:

e.g.

```
public $helpers = array('App');
```

Comment: If one wants to avoid having to modify baked templates, then it would probably be better to [**replace the `Number` helper**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#aliasing-helpers) with an API compatible custom/extended helper that uses 6 as the default places. ps., the question is about CakePHP 3, not CakePHP 2.

Comment: Or perhaps [customize your bake templates](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#customizing-the-bake-templates) to take into account the number of decimals defined in the schema, providing the `['places' => x]` parameter to the format function as required.

Comment: I thought that can be configured somewhere in Entities or Tables. Probably I expect too much from Cake.

Comment: I don't think you should change your values *before* the view... when calculating values, it might give you false results. So I believe the best way is to do it inside the view. Instead of `number` you could use: `$this->Number->precision($metric->data_multiplier, 6)`. Spares a few typestrokes...